# Ubuntu 22.04 hangs frequently with the error Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]

Tags: freeze

We are facing a ubuntu 22.04 system hang issue. When we searched the logs we can ablle to see the below error. Could someone help me with a solution. This issue occurs on a every day basis.
Sys config : 8 GB RAM, i3 11th gen, 2GB graphics card, 256 GB SSD.

```
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051370] INFO: task kworker/u8:6:74464 blocked for more than 483 seconds.
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051385]       Not tainted 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051391] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051394] task:kworker/u8:6    state:D stack:    0 pid:74464 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051406] Workqueue: events_unbound nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work [nouveau]
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051665] Call Trace:
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051669]  <TASK>
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051675]  __schedule+0x23d/0x590
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051686]  schedule+0x4e/0xb0
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051693]  schedule_timeout+0xfb/0x140
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051701]  ? nouveau_fence_enable_signaling+0x31/0x70 [nouveau]
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051928]  dma_fence_default_wait+0x1c4/0x1f0
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051937]  ? dma_fence_free+0x20/0x20
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051943]  dma_fence_wait_timeout+0xb7/0xd0
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.051951]  drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_fences+0x89/0xe0 [drm_kms_helper]
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052003]  nv50_disp_atomic_commit_tail+0x8a/0x8e0 [nouveau]
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052222]  ? psi_task_switch+0xc6/0x220
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052232]  nv50_disp_atomic_commit_work+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052446]  process_one_work+0x22b/0x3d0
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052458]  worker_thread+0x53/0x410
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052468]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052478]  kthread+0x12a/0x150
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052487]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052496]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Jun 18 17:35:35 mathu-nv09 kernel: [30572.052509]  </TASK>
```

Comment: How happened that you are using kernel 5.15 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Yes, anything wrong ? Kindly guide us

Comment: My comment was wrong. `5.15` is OK. But the error is showing that you are using an Nvidia GPU. What is the GPU? Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Ut can be done by

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Reboot after that.

Answer (score 0):

On debian or similar systems you can see the same thing. And in that case `sudo apt install nvidia-driver` will do the trick.